# Android TV - Bluetooth Low Energy Support

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-tv

I know this question is odd, but it's for a research project. Any app that I downloaded from the Google Play Store that allows Bluetooth LE scanning do not work: there are no results.

I went on an develop my own app to quickly test the two ways to perform LE scan :

**1) Using Prelollipop scan**

```
final BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
final boolean result = btAdapter.startLeScan(new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result = " + device.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
Toast.makeText(this, "result is = " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

And the logs printed after executing this code:

> D/BluetoothAdapter: startLeScan(): null
>
> D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
>
> D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5

**2) Using Lollipop+ scan:**

```
final BluetoothLeScanner leScanner = btAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
final ScanSettings scanSettings = new ScanSettings.Builder().setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).setReportDelay(0).build();
leScanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result = " + result.getDevice().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed = " + errorCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

And the logs printed after executing this code:

> D/BluetoothAdapter: STATE_ON
>
> D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5

In all cases, the app asks for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` at runtime, my Android TV running Marshmallow. Location is enabled (HIGH ACCURACY) in Android settings, and I use Google Maps to use Google Play Services to get my location (thus displaying the location icon on the notification bar).

The final results is that I do not get any results at all. Is it possible LE is not supported ?

Comment: Your code looks correct (I put it in a sample and it worked once I requested location permissions and triggered the scanning to stop at the right time).

I was getting null back for the name of the first device that scanned but I was able to find a lot of devices. If you remove the getName() from your toast, do you still find a devices? 

I know in the docs, it says a null name could be a problem but I did find some devices when I scanned (mDeviceName=LE-Bose QuietComfort 3)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getName()

Comment: This is also helpful to help get the logs for BLE scanning
https://source.android.com/source/read-bug-reports#scans

Comment: @benjamin thank you for your comments. Like you, I made sure to ask for the necessary permissions before starting any scans. Otherwise the logs would say something about it. In regards to the null name, it is indeed possible but that would not prevent the display of the toasts messages. Indeed, should the scanned device name be null, all I'd get would be `Result is null`. The problem I have is that there are no devices scanned whatsoever. Using my phone and some apps from the store I can see plenty around me, but no results with the same apps on the TV! Could it be a hardware limitation?

Comment: Bluetooth should be supported; the remote pairs over bluetooth. Which TV are you using? Nexus Player? Nvidia Shield? You might be right that there is a hardware issue with your TV.

Comment: @Benjamin I am using a Leelbox Q2 (not a TV), plugged to my monitor. It supports Bluetooth 4.0, though the remote is IR. Normal discovery scan and classic pairing does indeed work, but none of the Low Energy features work while they are indeed fully accessible. Even the discovery scan do not pick any LE devices.